# Path variable does not seem to be consistent in a single Powershell script

Tags: powershell, path

I'm running what **I** think is a relatively simple script:

```
$txtPath = "c:\users\xxxxxx\desktop\cgc\tx\" 
$srcfiles = Get-ChildItem $txtPath -filter "*.txt*"

ForEach($txtfile in $srcfiles) { 
        Write-Host $txtfile
        Get-Content $txtfile
}
```

and I get the following output:

```
Automatic_Post-Call_Survey_-_BC,_CC.txt
Get-Content : Cannot find path 'C:\users\x46332\desktop\cgc\Automatic_Post-Call_Survey_-_BC,_CC.txt' because it does no
t exist.
At C:\users\x46332\desktop\cgc\testcount2.ps1:34 char:13
+     Get-Content <<<<  $txtfile
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\users\x46332...ey_-_BC,_CC.txt:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundEx
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

This is the output from `Write-Host $txtfile` followed immediately by `Get-Content $txtfile` and `get-content` seems to be the heart of my issue.

When I comment out the `Get-Content` line, the script generates a list of the filenames to the console. This suggests to me that the `$txtPath` is properly defined. However, I add `Get-Content` for the SAME file/same variable and for some reason, the `\tx` portion of the path disappears from the search string. My filename prints, but then `Get-Content` can't find the path for the filename is just printed.

I suspect that the "directory doesn't exist" error isn't really that the directory doesn't exist. So what should I be looking at? There's not a lot of space in my code for an error to hide, but I can't find it...thoughts?

Comment: First, your script doesn't match with the output. You say $txtpath is a folder "tx", but the error shows a file outside. Also, see if `Get-Content -LiteralPath $txtfile` or `$txtfile | Get-Content` (they're almost the same) works. The filename contains a few special characters, and literalpath may handle those better

Comment: @Graimer - That's what I'm trying to understand...`Write-Host $txtfile` finds files INSIDE the `\tx` folder, but `Get-Content $txtfile` --same variable-- errors out OUTSIDE of the folder...where the file doesn't exist. I'm trying to understand why the two cmdlets are looking in different paths for the same variable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get-Content needs the full path e.g.:

```
Get-Content $txtFile.FullName
```

When you specify `Get-Content $txtFile`, PowerShell attempts to coerce the argument $txtFile to the required argument Path and to do so, it coerces the FileInfo object to a string.  This process yields just the name of the file.

Another way to do this is:

```
$txtFile | Get-Content
```

Comment: Bingo. That did it. Thanks for the tip about the different behavior for Get-Content!